# On using a plural for an action to be performed multiple times

Tags: grammatical-number

I've always wondered which of the following is correct:

- "I would like to give a speech on the 12th and the 17th"
- "I would like to give speeches on the 12th and the 17th"

In this scenario, I'm giving one speech on the 12th and another on the 17th.

Comment: It's the latter: you're giving two speeches.

Comment: I'd accept both as equally valid. If it was [essentially] the *same* speech, I'd probably lean more towards the singular.

Comment: The latter, unless both speeches are the same speech, in which case you could specify, "I would like to give my speech on ______ on both the 12th and the 17th" (fill in the blank with a speech title or topic, such as 'How To Save Money in Inflationary Times'). Don

Answer (score 1):

Both are standard, and both can refer to the same or to different speeches.

Consider something as ordinary as:

*We have executives from headquarters visiting this week. I need to wear a tie on Tuesday and Thursday.*

In my experience, no one would give a second thought to such language, it violates no widely held grammar prescription, and the context would determine whether it is important to specify if the same or different speeches or ties were contemplated. One could repeat the *on*: ... *on Tuesday and on Thursday*, but it can be elided with no problem and I expect it most likely would be in speech or written dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the second "on" to both sentences is more correct, but only as it relates to consistency in the structure of the two (making them both prepositional) phrases. The second alternative suggests you are giving more than one speech on each day. For both clarity and consistency, the correct statement would be, "I would like to give (sic) a speech on the 12th and on the 17th.

Answer (score -1):

Both could be correct, but you'd have to make a slight modification to the first one.

- "I would like to give a speech on the 12th and *on* the 17th"

That indicates two separate speeches (even if they are over the same topic). The second bullet you have is fine on its own.